# Do Airlines Rebook You on IROPS with Airport Changes?

Tags: united-airlines

Suppose I am flying BOS-LGA-EWR-SFO with a 5 hour layover between LGA and EWR-SFO. Suppose BOS-LGA was 3 hours late (because of Weather or ATC or Mechanical Failure) and I don't make it to EWR on time. Would the airline rebook me (for free)?

Comment: Did you purchase all your flights as a single ticket?

Comment: Yes. Everything is on one PNR>

Comment: How are you supposed to get from La Guardia to Newark?

Comment: For those not familiar with New York, LGA and EWR are two airports in the New York City area.  I presume you have booked one flight BOS-LGA and a second flight EWR-SFO, and are planning to get between them via ground transportation; the airline does not have a booking LGA-EWR for you?

Comment: @NateEldredge This is not uncommon. The ground transportation between the two airports (within the same city), including baggage, is left to the passenger. On the airline ticket (if you had a paper one) it would simply say NYC in the city column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, particularly in your circumstance where the airline can see it occurred because of a delayed inbound flight. In that condition the delay has encroached into the "minimum connect time" between LGA and EWR (which is three hours).

If you were involved in a delay between LGA and EWR I would also expect to be re-accommodated. However this is a bit more difficult to assert and prove.

(All of this relies on these flights being on a single ticket---that is, bought at the same time from one seller.)

By the way, you can write "LGA-EWR" as "LGA//EWR" to indicate that you are not flying between LGA and EWR but using alternative transportation.